# What is considered Kabbalas Lashon Hara?

Tags: lashon-hara-slander

If one listens and feels uncomfortable to protest, is that accepting lashon hara?

Must one verbally accept it?

Is it accepting if one merely accepts it in their heart but verbally says they do not accept?

Comment: Accepting it in the heart is definitely accepting it, and is not allowed. Verbally accepting it is not allowed for an entirely different reason: it is encouraging the speaker.